# Excel: #CALC! error (Nested Array) when using MAP functions for counting interval overlaps

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

I am struggling with the following formula, it works for some scenarios but not in all of them. The name `input` has the data set that is failing, getting an `#CALC!` error with the description "Nested Array":

```
=LET(input, {"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N1",10,20},
  names, INDEX(input,,1), namesUx, UNIQUE(names), dates, FILTER(input, {0,1,1}),
  byRowResult, BYROW(namesUx, LAMBDA(name,
    LET(set, FILTER(dates, names=name),
      startDates, INDEX(set,,1), endDates, INDEX(set,,2), onePeriod, IF(ROWS(startDates)=1, TRUE, FALSE),
      IF(onePeriod, IF(startDates <= IF(endDates > 0, endDates, startDates + 1),0, 1),
        LET(seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(startDates)),
          mapResult, MAP(startDates, endDates, seq, LAMBDA(start,end,idx,
            LET(incIdx, 1-N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(seq,idx))),
              startInc, FILTER(startDates, incIdx), endInc, FILTER(endDates, incIdx),
              MAP(startInc, endInc,LAMBDA(ss,ee, N(AND(start <= ee, end >= ss))))
              ))),
              SUM(mapResult)))
    ))), HSTACK(namesUx, byRowResult)
)
```

If we replace the `input` values in previous formula with the following range: `A2:C4`, in `G1:H1` would be the **expected output**:

[image: sample input and output]

Provided also a graphical representation to visualize the intervals and their corresponding overlap. From the screenshot, we have `2` overlaps.

If we use the above formula for the same range we get the following output:

[image: sample excel input output with error]

If we hover the `#CALC!` cell, it informs about the specific error:

[image: Error description]

Let's explain the input data and what the formula does:

**Input data**

- First column: N1, N2, N3, represents names
- Second Column: Start of the interval (I am using numeric values, but in my real situation will be dates)
- Third Column: End of the interval (I am using numeric values, but in my real situation will be dates)

**Formula**

The purpose of the formula is to identify for each unique `names`, how many intervals overlap. The calculation goes by each row (`BYROW`) of the unique names and for each pair of start-end values, counts the overlaps with respect to the other start-end values. I use `FILTER` to exclude the current start-end pair with the following condition: `FILTER(startDates, incIdx)` and I tested it works properly.

The condition to exclude the start data of the current name of the iteration of `BYROW` is the following:

```
1-N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(seq,idx)))
```

and used as second input argument of the `FILTER` function.

The rest is just to check the [overlap range condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap).

I separate the logic when a `name` has only one interval, from the rest because the calculation is different, For a single interval I just want to check that the end date comes after start date and treat the special case of `0`. This particular case I tested it works.

**Testing and workarounds**

I already isolated *where* is the issue and *when* it happens. The problem happens in the following call:

```
MAP(startInc, endInc,LAMBDA(ss,ee, N(AND(start <= ee, end >= ss))))
```

when `startInc` and `endInc` has more than one row. It has nothing to do with the content of the `LAMBDA` function. I can use:

```
MAP(startInc, endInc,LAMBDA(ss,ee, 1))
```

and still fails. The problem is with the input arrays: `startInc`, `endInc`. If I use any other array for example the following ones it doesn't works:

```
MAP(seq,LAMBDA(ss, 1))
```

Similar result using `names`, `startDates`, etc, even if I use: `{1;2;3}` fails. If use use `idx` it works, because it is not an array. Therefore the error happens with any type of array or range.

I have also tested that the input arguments are correct having the correct shape and values. For example replacing the `MAP` function with: `TEXTJOIN(",",, startInc)&" ; "` (and also with `endInc`) and replacing `SUM` with `CONCAT` to concatenate the result.

In terms of input data I tested the following scenarios:

```
{"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10} -> Works
{"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N2",10,0;"N2",10,20;"N3",20,10} -> Works
{"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N1",10,20} -> Error
{"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N1",10,0} -> Error
{"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N1",10,0;"N1",20,10} -> Error
{"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N2",10,0;"N2",10,20;"N2",20,10} -> Error
```

The cases that work are because it goes to the `MAP` function an array of size `1` (number of duplicated names is less than `3`)

I did some research on internet about [#CALC!](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-calc-error-d6ee03c5-daf6-426a-8df5-4b284730ab1b) error, but there is no too much details about this error and it is provided only a very trivial case. I didn't find any indication in the limit of nested calls of the new arrays functions: `BYROW`, `MAP`, etc.

**Conclusion**, it seems that the following nested structure produce this error:

```
=MAP({1;2;3}, LAMBDA(n, MAP({4;5;6}, LAMBDA(s, TRUE))))
```

even for a trivial case like this.

On contrary the following situation works:

```
=MAP({1;2;3}, LAMBDA(n, REDUCE("",{4;5;6}, LAMBDA(a,s, TRUE))))
```

because the output of `REDUCE` is not an array.

Any suggestion on how to circumvent this limitation in my original formula?, Is this a real situation of an array that cannot use another array as input?, Is it a bug?

Comment: Not sure I understand. It's simply by design that `LAMBDA`'s *calculation* parameter should return a single value and not an array. As to alternative solutions, it might be more helpful to have a few example inputs with expected outputs; modifying your current formula might prove to be more time-consuming than attacking the problem from scratch.

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley you made a good point. I found a way to circumvent the error removing the second `MAP`. I provided an answer with additional details, but I haven't accepted it, in case other people can provide a better one. Added a sample input/output in the question in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JosWoolley pointed out:

> `LAMBDA`'s calculation parameter should return a single value and not an
> array

I haven't seen that way, or deduced it from [#CALC! Nested Array error definition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-calc-error-nested-array-ffa5997d-a440-4e41-aae9-8b39c4a8dfb9):

> The nested array error occurs when you try to input an array formula
> that contains an array. To resolve the error, try removing the second
> array...For example, `=MUNIT({1,2})` is asking Excel to return
> a `1x1` array, and a `2x2` array, which isn't currently supported.
> `=MUNIT(2)` would calculate as expected

so the alternative is then to remove this second `MAP` call. The following link gave me an idea about how to do it: [Identify overlapping dates and times in Excel](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/identify-overlapping-dates-and-times-in-excel#:%7E:text=With%20SUMPRODUCT%20we%20can%20check,know%20there%20are%20overlapping%20dates), therefore using `SUMPRODUCT` or `SUM` can serve the purpose.

```
=LET(input, {"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N1",10,20},
  names, INDEX(input,,1), namesUx, UNIQUE(names), dates, FILTER(input, {0,1,1}),
  byRowResult, BYROW(namesUx, LAMBDA(name,
    LET(set, FILTER(dates, names=name),
      startDates, INDEX(set,,1), endDates, INDEX(set,,2), 
      onePeriod, IF(ROWS(startDates)=1, TRUE, FALSE),
      IF(onePeriod, IF(startDates <= IF(endDates > 0, endDates, startDates + 1),0, 1),
        LET(seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(startDates)),
          mapResult, MAP(startDates, endDates, seq, LAMBDA(start,end,idx,
            LET(incIdx, 1-N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(seq,idx))),
              startInc, FILTER(startDates, incIdx), endInc, FILTER(endDates, incIdx),
              SUMPRODUCT((startInc <= end) * (endInc >= start ))
              ))),SUM(mapResult)))/2
    ))), HSTACK(namesUx, byRowResult)
)
```

We need to divide by `2` the result, because we are counting the overlapping in both directions. `A` overlaps with `B` and vice versa.

It can be further simplified because there is no need to build the names: `startInc`, `endInc` to exclude the range itself we are checking for overlap.  We can include it and subtract one overlap. This is the way to do it:

```
=LET(input, {"N1",0,0;"N1",0,10;"N1",10,20},
  names, INDEX(input,,1), namesUx, UNIQUE(names), dates, FILTER(input, {0,1,1}),
  byRowResult, BYROW(namesUx, LAMBDA(name,
    LET(set, FILTER(dates, names=name),
      startDates, INDEX(set,,1), endDates, INDEX(set,,2), 
      onePeriod, IF(ROWS(startDates)=1, TRUE, FALSE),
      IF(onePeriod, IF(startDates <= IF(endDates > 0, 
        endDates, startDates + 1),0, 1),
        SUM(MAP(startDates, endDates, LAMBDA(start,end,
          SUMPRODUCT((startDates <= end) * (endDates >= start ))-1)))/2)
    ))), HSTACK(namesUx, byRowResult)
)
```

Here, the output, removing the array as input and using the corresponding range `A2:C4`. Providing also a graphical representations of the intervals (highlighted) and in cell `G2` putting the corresponding previous formula:

[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: Since we are using `SUMPRODUCT` with a single input, it can be replaced with `SUM`.