# Sequence a 'sumif' with exclusions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sheets that autocalculate the P&L for each project. At the moment they're using a fixed salary, but I'd like to change it to incorporate any future salary changes. The project duration is Sequenced from L1 based on a duration parameter in E2 using `=EDATE($C$2, SEQUENCE(1, $E$2, 0))`

Each cell in column L sequences through the duration, calculating the relevant values.

[image: P&L]

The formula for the salary costs refences the dataset below which is also automatically generated from data in another sheet using `=FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Code Name]=B2), {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0})` and can have a variable number of entries:

[image: Project]

The current formua for calculating the salary costs in L7 (from the first image) that someone on here kindly helped me with is `=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($A$18#),1,0),($L$1#>=OFFSET($A$18#,0,3,,1))*($L$1#<=OFFSET($A$18#,0,4,,1))*OFFSET($A$18#,0,5,,1))` and uses the column F (which I'm hoping to remove) from the second image .

I've got a new set of data in the table EmployeeSalaryTbl for the salaries here (I had to add in the made up end date of 31/12/9999 for now to ensure calculations work below. Ideally, this would be blank, and I'd check for that in the below calculation):

[image: salaries]

I've begun modifying the MMult function in L7 to do the following:

1. Sequence for the duration of the project
2. Check if the employees from A18 onwards are on the project for the given month starting from L1
3. If they are then find the salary that falls within the date range from the EmployeeSalaryTbl and add them all together for the month.

This is what I have so far but unfortunately it's giving me an error:

`=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS($A$18#),1,0),IF(AND(($L$1#>=OFFSET($A$18#,0,3,,1))*($L$1#<=OFFSET($A$18#,0,4,,1))),SUMIFS(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Monthly], EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],$A$18#, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date],"<="&$L$1#, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date],">="&$L$1#),0))`

The data for the Project defined by image 2 is:

| Employee | Role | Discipline | Start Date | End Date | Salary Monthly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Senior Programmer | Programming | 12/01/2020 | 06/05/2020 | £4,333 |
| Dave | Mid Level Programmer | Programming | 01/02/2020 | 30/05/2020 | £3,167 |
| Peter | Senior Programmer | Programming | 01/01/2020 | 31/01/2020 | £4,583 |
| Jack | Junior Programmer | Programming | 01/02/2020 | 30/06/2020 | £2,083 |
| Richard | Senior Artist | Art | 01/03/2020 | 30/04/2020 | £3,750 |
| Rodney | Lead QA | QA | 01/03/2020 | 30/06/2020 | £4,333 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 1 | Senior Producer | Production | 01/02/2020 | 30/05/2020 | £3,458 |
| Roger | QA | QA | 01/01/2020 | 30/04/2020 | £1,667 |
| Wesley | Mid Level Programmer | Programming | 01/02/2020 | 31/05/2020 | £3,750 |
| Rachel | Senior Artist | Art | 01/01/2020 | 30/06/2020 | £3,333 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 2 | Lead Programmer | Programming | 01/01/2020 | 31/07/2020 | £4,417 |

And the data in for the EmployeeSalaryTbl is:

| Employee | Salary Start Date | Salary End Date | Salary | Salary Monthly | Salary Daily |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 01/01/2020 | 31/03/2021 | £52,000 | £4,333 | £199 |
| Bob | 01/04/2021 | 31/03/2022 | £55,000 | £4,583 | £211 |
| Bob | 01/04/2022 | 31/12/9999 | £58,000 | £4,833 | £222 |
| Dave | 01/01/2020 | 31/03/2021 | £38,000 | £3,167 | £146 |
| Dave | 01/04/2021 | 31/12/9999 | £42,000 | £3,500 | £161 |
| Wesley | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £45,000 | £3,750 | £173 |
| Jack | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £25,000 | £2,083 | £96 |
| Richard | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £45,000 | £3,750 | £173 |
| Rodney | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £52,000 | £4,333 | £199 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 1 | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £41,500 | £3,458 | £159 |
| Roger | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £20,000 | £1,667 | £77 |
| Steve | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £27,000 | £2,250 | £104 |
| Rachel | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £40,000 | £3,333 | £153 |
| Peter | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £34,000 | £2,833 | £130 |
| Sarah | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £22,000 | £1,833 | £84 |
| Chloe | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £33,000 | £2,750 | £127 |
| Matthew | 01/01/2020 | 31/03/2021 | £23,000 | £1,917 | £88 |
| Matthew | 01/04/2021 | 31/12/9999 | £28,000 | £2,333 | £107 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 2 | 01/01/2020 | 31/12/9999 | £36,000 | £3,000 | £138 |

Comment: I assume per tags used you don't have an excel version constraint.

Comment: If I got the sense of your request, you could get the expected result with a formula similar to this: `=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee]),1,0),($L$1#>=EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date])*($L$1#<=EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date])*EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Monthly])`. This formula is very similar to what you used with the previous table, but mainly I replaced the `OFFSET` parts with spill ranges, with table notations. My simulation with your data works fine, but there may be problems if salaries are changed in a date which is not either first or last day of the month.

Comment: Hi @Michele I need the offset parts as they determine whether the staff member is allocated to the project that month

Comment: Hi @DavidLeal I am on Excel 365 and I don't believe I have any constraints

Comment: Hi @AutomationMonkey, in order to determine whether staff member is allocated in the month this could be the formula: `=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee]),1,0),($L$1#>=EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date])*($L$1#<=EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date])*EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Monthly]*($L$1#>=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],CHOOSECOLS($A$18#,1),CHOOSECOLS($A$18#,4)),0))*($L$1#<=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],CHOOSECOLS($A$18#,1),CHOOSECOLS($A$18#,5)),0)))`. It works in my simulation, but my previous consideration on salaries is still applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your input data, and assuming no Excel version constraints (not specified in the question), in cell `H2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(namePrj, TB_Prj[Employee], startPrj, TB_Prj[Start Date], endPrj,
 TB_Prj[End Date],name, TB_Roster[Employee],start, TB_Roster[Salary Start Date],
 end, TB_Roster[Salary End Date],salary, TB_Roster[Salary Monthly],
 SOMs, H1:S1, EOMs, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
 namesActive, FILTER(namePrj, (startPrj <= SOM) * (endPrj >= EOM)),
  cost, FILTER(salary, (start <= SOM) * (IF(end > 0, end, EOM) >= EOM) *
    (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(name,namesActive))),0), sum(cost)
  )))
 )
```

Two *Excel Tables* were defined to have dynamic ranges: `TB_Prj` for project information and `TB_Roster` for salary information. The month information is generated horizontally as follows in `H1`:

```
=EDATE(DATE(2020,1,1), SEQUENCE(1, 12, 0))
```

It generates the first day of the month. Represented in the formula as `SOMs` (Start Of the Month). Similarly, I use `EOMs` to represent each corresponding End Of the Month.

The output generates a `1x12` array as result.

Here is the output:

[image: sample output in Excel]

Showing only partially the salary table (`TB_Roster`)

**Notes**:

Please check the result, your **data needs to be cleaned**, for example, Peter in Salary Table has two entries overlapping the date interval.

If you cannot use tables (for example the input is based on SPILL formula like `FILTER`), then ranges can be used instead. You can define the following two data set ranges: `prjSet`, `rosterSet`, then define each corresponding column like this: `INDEX(rng,,x)`, where `x` represents the corresponding column number on each range where `rng` is `prjSet` or `rosterSet`. For example `name` variable could be defined like this:

```
namePrj, INDEX(prjSet,,1)
```

### Explanation

Using *Excel Tables* to have dynamic ranges, so the formula doesn't need to change when additional information is added. We use `LET` function to make the formula easier to maintain, defining the required inputs and intermediate results.

`BYCOL` is used to iterate over all `SOMs` values. For each start of the month (`SOM`), we do the following:

Find the `namesActive` from active projects checking that the start of the project is before or equal to `SOM` and the end of the project is greater or equal to `EOM`. In case no names from the project table satisfy the condition, `FILTER` returns an error (`#CALC!`) because empty arrays are not permitted in Excel. If this situation wants to be treated the formula needs to be adjusted (using a third input argument of `FILTER` and `IF` condition for computing `cost`) or better to clean the data. I would not expect for a given month not having any active project at a company level.

Once we have the list of names, we go to the second Excel Table (`TB_Roster`) to find a valid salary based on `start`, `end` dates.

We treat empty values in `end`, assuming that if there is no value (data is formatted as date, so empty means `0`). The following `IF` condition ensures it (in the second `FILTER` call):

```
(IF(end > 0, end, EOM) >= EOM)
```

so if `end` array is positive (dates are represented as positive integers starting from `0`, i.e. *whole numbers*), then a value was assigned, so we use this value, otherwise (`0`) it is replaced by `EOM`. When there is no end date the condition it is *always true* (all `end` values are considered). `IF` works with arrays, it evaluates the condition on each element of the array and returns the corresponding value on each element. By doing this we fixed the case of empty value to a valid situation, so there is *no need to use a fictitious date*.

The condition related to `XMATCH`, ensures we filter `name` by only the names on the previous `FILTER` call (valid names from the project table, i.e. `namesActive`). The result of this filter (`cost`) satisfies all the conditions and returns all matching monthly salaries.

In case there is no match based on the filter conditions, we return `0` (but another value can be used, for example `NA()`). In order to do that we use the third input argument of `FILTER` function.

Finally, we sum all the salaries that match the condition.

### Bonus: Checking Interval Consistency

Based on the answer to the question: [Excel: #CALC! error (Nested Array) when using MAP functions for counting interval overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74242820/excel-calc-error-nested-array-when-using-map-functions-for-counting-interva) provided by me. It can be adapted to check if date intervals are incorrect (end date before start date) or if intervals overlap for Salary Table:

```
=LET(names, TB_Roster[Employee], namesUx, UNIQUE(names),
 dates, TB_Roster[Salary Start Date]:TB_Roster[Salary End Date],
 maxDate, DATE(3000,1,1),
  byRowResult, BYROW(namesUx, LAMBDA(name,
    LET(set, FILTER(dates, names=name),
      startDates, INDEX(set,,1), endDates, INDEX(set,,2),
      calc, MAP(startDates, endDates, LAMBDA(start,end,
        LET(endAdj, IF(end > 0, end, maxDate),
        endDatesAdj, IF(endDates > 0, endDates, maxDate),
        startAfterEnd, IF(start <= endAdj, 0, 1),
        overlaps, IF(startAfterEnd > 0, 0,
          SUMPRODUCT((startDates <= endAdj) * (endDatesAdj >= start))-1),
        startAfterEnd &","& overlaps))),
        totals, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,calc),",",";"), intervals,
          1*INDEX(totals,,1), laps, 1*INDEX(totals,,2),
        SUM(intervals) + SUM(laps)/2
      )
    )), FILTER(HSTACK(namesUx, byRowResult), byRowResult<>0,
          "NO Overlaps or Wrong Ranges defined")
)
```

and the output will be for your input data:

[image: Sample Excel spreadsheet/cells for checking inconsistencies]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation, I'm going to work through this now. One thing I forgot to mention in my question was I'd like to support part months. So if the employee starts mid month or ends mid month then it calculates the remaining working days and multiplies this by the 'Salary Daily' from the EmployeeSalaryTbl. Is this possible with the above solution?

Comment: Hi @David The data defined by TB_Prj in the solution above is actually defined by a `filter =FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Code Name]=B2), {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0})` that pulls from another set of data in mine. I don't believe it can be a table, or can I make it one somehow? If not, how do I incorporate the data without a table?

Comment: In an attempt to replace the TB_prj and also make the SOMs dynamic I adjusted the first part of the forumla to the following but this just gives me a sequence of 0's: `namePrj, $A$18#, startPrj, $D$18#, endPrj, 
$E$18#, name, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],start, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date], 
 end, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date],salary, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Monthly], 
 SOMs, $L$1#,`

Comment: Fixing the datasets makes it work but obviously doesn't support the dynamic nature of the data from L18 onwards. Leaving SOMs as $L$1# works for sequencing the duration though `namePrj, A18:A28, startPrj, D18:D28, endPrj,
E18:E28, name, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],start, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date],
 end, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date],salary, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Monthly],
 SOMs, $L$1#`

Comment: thanks for the spot in the test salary data too. I've removed the first salary entry for Peter in the test salary data in the question above.

Comment: I've also noticed an issue with the results. So leaving in the incorrect entry for Peter I get the same result as yourself for January. However, if I add up the salary amounts for the staff on the project in january I get a different result. It looks like it's not adding in the salary for Bob because if I remove Bob I get the same result as your example. Is this because Bob is only on it for a part month? If so, is there a way to solve the part months to use the per day salary for the working dyas they're on it that month? I'd like it to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: @AutomationMonkey I removed the line you removed in your question for Peter, please let's check the result without any changes. Once it is validated for the input data, then check other scenarios changing the input data, and finally modifying or adapting the formula. I will update the picture in my answer. Now I am getting for Jan the salary cost of:  `£10,833.00`would you confirm that?

Comment: I can confirm that I have £10,833 for the first month of January. Regards setting up a named range prjSet for A18 onwards, I then attempted to switch in the named range suggestion, defining Project1Dataset as `='Project 1 Test'!$A$18#` and then adjusting the function to `namePrj, INDEX(Project1Dataset,,1), startPrj, INDEX(Project1Dataset,,4), endPrj,
INDEX(Project1Dataset,,5)`, unfortunately this gave 0's. I then switched the range to `='Project 1 Test'!$A$18:A28` for testing and the result was also 0's. I can't use a fixed dataset as it's alsways changing.

Comment: Additionally, I create the project sheet dynamically so using a named range isn't ideal as the user would have to add a new named range and inject it in to the formula for the salary costs. I could create the named range using vba on sheet creation and somehow inject the named range change in to the formula for salary costs. Ideally there'd be a solution without having to do this though.

Comment: It should work, without looking at your file it is difficult to say something. `Project1Dataset` can be defined like that and this is the way to create the variable `namePrj`. Use the following trick for testing purposes **only**: replace `sum(cost)` with: `result, sum(cost), namePrj`. This will return this name variable instead, just to check the variable was properly defined. You can use the same idea for checking any other name defined in the first `LET` call

Comment: That is giving me a calc error now

Comment: func `=LET(namePrj, INDEX(Project1Dataset,,1), startPrj, INDEX(Project1Dataset,,4), endPrj,
INDEX(Project1Dataset,,5), name, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],start, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date],
 end, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date],salary, EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Monthly],
 SOMs, $L$1#, EOMs, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
 namesActive, FILTER(namePrj, (startPrj <= SOM) * (endPrj >= EOM)),
  cost, FILTER(salary, (start <= SOM) * (IF(end > 0, end, EOM) >= EOM) *
    (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(name,namesActive))),0), result, SUM(cost), namePrj
  )))
 )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249197/discussion-between-david-leal-and-automation-monkey).

Comment: Using =OFFSET('Project 1'!A18,0,0,COUNTA('Project 1'!$A$18:$A$10000),COUNTA('Project 1'!$A$17:$F$17)) for the named range allows it to be dynamic. This solution works for me since the data defined by the Filter is dynamic. It works when I copy the template sheet too, I just need to create a new name for the duplicated named range Project1Dataset when prompted which automatically corrects the entries in the Let function for the new sheet.