# Calculating partial months salary costings for employees on a project in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following input data with **Employee** and project information (dates in `MM/DD/YYYY` format):

| Employee | Role | Discipline | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Senior Programmer | Programming | 12/1/2020 | 5/3/2021 |
| Dave | Mid Level Programmer | Programming | 1/2/2020 | 5/30/2020 |
| Peter | Senior Programmer | Programming | 1/2/2020 | 1/30/2020 |
| Jack | Junior Programmer | Programming | 1/2/2020 | 6/30/2020 |
| Richard | Senior Artist | Art | 1/3/2020 | 4/30/2020 |
| Rodney | Lead QA | QA | 1/3/2020 | 6/30/2020 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 1 | Senior Producer | Production | 1/2/2020 | 5/30/2020 |
| Roger | QA | QA | 1/1/2020 | 4/30/2020 |
| Wesley | Mid Level Programmer | Programming | 1/2/2020 | 5/31/2020 |
| Rachel | Senior Artist | Art | 1/1/2020 | 6/30/2020 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 2 | Lead Programmer | Programming | 1/1/2020 | 7/31/2020 |

Then I have the roster table with salary information about each employee:

| Employee | Salary Start Date | Salary End Date | Salary | Monthly Salary | Daily Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2021 | $ 52,000 | $ 4,333 | $ 217 |
| Bob | 4/1/2021 | 3/31/2022 | $ 55,000 | $ 4,583 | $ 229 |
| Bob | 4/1/2022 |  | $ 58,000 | $ 4,833 | $ 242 |
| Dave | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2021 | $ 38,000 | $ 3,167 | $ 158 |
| Dave | 4/1/2021 |  | $ 42,000 | $ 3,500 | $ 175 |
| Wesley | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 45,000 | $ 3,750 | $ 188 |
| Jack | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 25,000 | $ 2,083 | $ 104 |
| Richard | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 45,000 | $ 3,750 | $ 188 |
| Rodney | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 52,000 | $ 4,333 | $ 217 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 1 | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 41,500 | $ 3,458 | $ 173 |
| Roger | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 20,000 | $ 1,667 | $ 83 |
| Steve | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 27,000 | $ 2,250 | $ 113 |
| Rachel | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 40,000 | $ 3,333 | $ 167 |
| Peter | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 34,000 | $ 2,833 | $ 142 |
| Sarah | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 22,000 | $ 1,833 | $ 92 |
| Chloe | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 33,000 | $ 2,750 | $ 138 |
| Matthew | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2021 | $ 23,000 | $ 1,917 | $ 96 |
| Matthew | 4/1/2021 |  | $ 28,000 | $ 2,333 | $ 117 |
| Proj 1 - Hire 2 | 1/1/2020 |  | $ 36,000 | $ 3,000 | $ 150 |

The following conditions apply to the above table:

1. An employee can have more than one salary but the corresponding intervals cannot overlap (**Start**/**End Dates** columns) - Used for annual salary increases.
2. If the **End Date** value is empty, the employee is currently on the set salary.

I posted a related question: *[Sequence a 'sumif' with exclusions in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253310/sequence-a-sumif-with-exclusions-in-excel)*, to calculate Monthly Salary cost, considering only total month assignment, i.e. the resource is allocated only if the employee was allocated the entire month.

Now I would like to consider partial allocations, i.e. to calculate the cost based on the total number of working days (Monday to Friday) an employee was allocated for the partial months defined by the **Start Date** and **End Date** considering the value of the **Daily Salary** column from the previous table. I was trying to adapt the formula from [the answer provided by DavidLeal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253310/sequence-a-sumif-with-exclusions-in-excel/74257548#74257548), but I was not able to find a way to accommodate it.

Here is the formula used to solve the previous question for non-partial allocation.

```
=LET(namePrj, TB_Prj[Employee], startPrj, TB_Prj[Start Date], endPrj,
 TB_Prj[End Date],name, TB_Roster[Employee],start, TB_Roster[Salary Start Date],
 end, TB_Roster[Salary End Date],salary, TB_Roster[Salary Monthly],
 SOMs, H1:S1, EOMs, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
 namesActive, FILTER(namePrj, (startPrj <= SOM) * (endPrj >= EOM)),
  cost, FILTER(salary, (start <= SOM) * (IF(end > 0, end, EOM) >= EOM) *
    (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(name,namesActive))),0), sum(cost)
  )))
 )
```

I am looking for an Excel formula that will return the Monthly Salary Cost for the first month of the sequence:

```
=EDATE(DATE(2020,1,1), SEQUENCE(1, 12, 0))
```

and then extend it to the end of the period or just return a `1x12` array for the entire period `1/1/2020-12/31/2020`.

Comment: This is not a question, this is a project. Much like we are doing your work.

Comment: Check out all the date functions, networkdays.intl() will consider holidays & weekends for example. Then sumproduct() and if() may also help.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike unfortunately that wouldn't work for my purpose. I need the correct salary amount for a given month. I think I'm on the right track above with having a few additional helper functions but I'm still relatively new to Excel and it's functions so I'm not sure how to sitck the right ones together to get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: I might've overlooked, but where is the start and end date of the project mentioned? Or are the start and end day of the employees from the project schedule always within the range of the project?

Comment: Don't think you could have tested all the 3 functions I suggested thoroughly in that time between my post and your reply.

Comment: Also if you're relatively new to excel, would you understand the formula David Leal provided you? Why ask for a `LET` solution if a step by step formula / helper columns would make  it all better understandable?

Comment: @AutomationMonkey I don't think you need the two additional columns, just the equivalent daily salary for each employee from the roster table. The rest can be calculated on the fly

Comment: Edited the question simplified the request and the description of the problem. I will like to post an answer. @P.b, SolarMike, MayukhBhattacharya. Thanks

Comment: Please would be possible to review the submitted edit of the question so the question can be opened again? @SolarMike, Mayukh, P.b I would like to post my answer. Thanks

Comment: You should probably just use Resource Management by Smartsheet or something for this instead of rolling your own fragile, isolated solution in Excel.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In cell `I2`, put the following formula (see **UPDATE** section for a simplified version):

```
=LET(setPrj, A2:E12, setRoster, A15:F33, SOMs, I1:T1,
 namesPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,1), startsPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,4), endsPrj,
 INDEX(setPrj,,5),names, INDEX(setRoster,,1),starts, INDEX(setRoster,,2),
 ends, INDEX(setRoster,,3),
 salaries,INDEX(setRoster,,6), empty, ",,",
 SPLIT, LAMBDA(x,case, LET(y, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,x),",",";"), z,
   FILTER(y, INDEX(y,,1)<>"", NA()),
     IFS(case=0, z,case=1, HSTACK(INDEX(z,,1), 1*CHOOSECOLS(z,2,3)), case=2, 1*z))),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),endsAdj, IF(ends > 0, ends, EOM),
  overlapsPrj, MAP(namesPrj, startsPrj, endsPrj, LAMBDA(namePrj,startPrj,endPrj,
   IF(AND(startPrj <= EOM, endPrj >= SOM),
   TEXTJOIN(",",,namePrj, MAX(startPrj, SOM), MIN(endPrj, EOM)), empty))),
   setPrjAdj, SPLIT(overlapsPrj,1),
   overlapsRoster, IF(ISNA(ROWS(setPrjAdj)), NA(),
    MAP(INDEX(setPrjAdj,,1), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,2), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,3),
      LAMBDA(name,start,end,
      LET(found, FILTER(HSTACK(starts, endsAdj, salaries), (names=name) * (starts <= end)
        * (endsAdj >= start), NA()), IF(AND(ROWS(found)=1, NOT(ISNA(found))),
        TEXTJOIN(",",, MAX(INDEX(found,,1), start),
          MIN(INDEX(found,,2), end), INDEX(found,,3)), empty)
    )))
  ),setRosterAdj, SPLIT(overlapsRoster,2),
  IF(ISNA(ROWS(setRosterAdj)), 0,
    LET(startEffDates, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,1), endEffDates, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,2),
      effSalaries, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,3),days, NETWORKDAYS(startEffDates, endEffDates),
      SUMPRODUCT(days, effSalaries)
    ))
  )))
)
```

And here is the output in a single array `1x12` for the entire period.

[image: Sample Excel file]

**Note**: In cell `I15` I am using the idea suggested in the answer to the question: [sequence a sumif with exclusions in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253310/sequence-a-sumif-with-exclusions-in-excel) provided by me for checking that the intervals of the roster data set don't overlap.

### UPDATE

The formula can be simplified as follow. There is no need to define a user `LAMBDA` function: `SPLIT`. We can make the `MAP` function to return only the index position of the overlaps, and then use this information to find the rest of the information. We use also `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK/HSTACK` combination to return multiple values (we were limited by `MAP` on returning only a single column)

```
=LET(setPrj, A2:E12, setRoster, A15:F33, SOMs, I1:T1,namesPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,1),
 startsPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,4), endsPrj,INDEX(setPrj,,5),names, INDEX(setRoster,,1),
 starts, INDEX(setRoster,,2), ends, INDEX(setRoster,,3), salaries,INDEX(setRoster,,6),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM, 0), endsAdj, IF(ends > 0, ends, EOM),
  overlapsPrj, MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(setPrj)), startsPrj, endsPrj,
    LAMBDA(idx, startPrj, endPrj,IF(AND(startPrj <= EOM, endPrj >= SOM),
    idx, 0))), pIdx, FILTER(overlapsPrj, overlapsPrj > 0, NA()),
  overlapsRoster, IF(ISNA(ROWS(pIdx)), NA(), DROP(REDUCE(0,pIdx,
    LAMBDA(acc, idx, VSTACK(acc, LET(name, INDEX(namesPrj,idx),
    start, MAX(INDEX(startsPrj,idx), SOM), end, MIN(INDEX(endsPrj,idx), EOM),
    found, FILTER(HSTACK(starts, endsAdj, salaries), (names=name) * (starts <= end)
      * (endsAdj >= start), NA()),
    IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(found)), ROWS(found)=1), HSTACK(MAX(start, INDEX(found,1,1)),
      MIN(end, INDEX(found,1,2)), INDEX(found,1,3)),{0,0,0})
    )))),1)), rEff, FILTER(overlapsRoster, INDEX(overlapsRoster,,3) > 0, NA()),
  IF(ISNA(ROWS(rEff)),0, LET(effStarts, INDEX(rEff,,1), effEnds,
    INDEX(rEff,,2), effSalaries, INDEX(rEff,,3),days, NETWORKDAYS(effStarts, effEnds),
    SUMPRODUCT(days, effSalaries)
  )))))
 )
```

### Explanation

#### General Idea

For the calculation we use two main ideas:

1. The condition for checking if two intervals (`A`,`B`) overlap:

   `(StartA <= EndB) AND (EndA >= StartB) -> TRUE`
2. If two intervals `A`,`B` overlap, the intersection of both intervals are:

   `[MAX(StartA, StartB), MIN(EndA, EndB)]`

We are going to iterate through each month. First look into the project dataset for interval overlaps on a given month, and for each interval that overlaps with the current month to find the intersection.

Once we have the list of resources with their corresponding intersections. We need to find the corresponding salary that matches the interval. We iterate again for the intersections found in the project dataset but now looking for a second intersection in the salary dataset.

#### Formula

We use `LET` function to define the inputs and intermediate results. We start defining two datasets `setPrj` for the data representing the project information and `setRoster` for the Roster information and related names required from the input set.

We are going to use `MAP` function (for finding each overlap) which is very convenient for doing transformations, it can take several input arrays of the same size, **but** then it returns a single array. To circumvent this, the output of `MAP` will be an `nx1` array and on each row, the information will be a string with comma-separated values (CSV). We define inside of `LET` a user custom `LAMBDA` function to convert the result back from CSV format to a 2D array.

This user function is named `SPLIT` (don't confuse it with `TEXTSPLIT` standard Excel function). Defining this function inside of `LET` function, the scope is limited to that function and there is no need to create a named range for that.

```
SPLIT, LAMBDA(x,case, LET(y, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,x),",",";"),
  z, FILTER(y, INDEX(y,,1)<>"", NA()),
  IFS(case=0, z,case=1, HSTACK(INDEX(z,,1),
    1*CHOOSECOLS(z,2,3)), case=2, 1*z)))
```

Because the input argument `x` will be an `nx1` array of comma-separated values, once we convert it to a 2D array, we need to convert some columns back to their original data type. We use the second input argument `case`, to consider all cast scenarios used in the main formula.

- `case=1`, converts columns `2` and `3` to numbers
- `case=2`, converts all columns to numbers

**Note**: `case=0`, is not used in the main formula, provided for testing purposes only. The `MAP` output will be in both calls an array of three columns.

Finally, the output will be an `nxm` array that has been removed the empty rows (`",,"`. There is a name defined for that: `empty`). In case all rows are empty, `FILTER` will return an error (the empty set doesn't exist in Excel), to prevent that we use the third input argument of this function to return `NA()`(we use the same idea in other parts of the main formula)

Now we use `BYCOL` to iterate over the months (we use this function because the months are in column format). For each month (represented as the first day of the month) we use `SOM`(Start of the month) and `EOM` (End of the Month) names to find the overlaps and intersections. The first `MAP` call does it and the result is named `intersecPrj`:

```
MAP(namesPrj, startsPrj, endsPrj, LAMBDA(namePrj,startPrj,endPrj,
  IF(AND(startPrj <= EOM, endPrj >= SOM),
  TEXTJOIN(",",,namePrj, MAX(startPrj, SOM), MIN(endPrj, EOM)), empty)))
```

**Note**: Here we can use `FILTER` instead of `MAP`, but with the latter we can find the overlap and the intersection at the same time. The result is stored in CSV format by row with the following information: `name, startDate, endDate` where the dates represent the intersection dates.

Now we convert back the information to a 2D array via the `SPLIT` function: `SPLIT(intersecPrj,1)`, because we want to keep the `name` as text we use `case=1` and name it as: `setPrjAdj` it is an array `nx3` where `n` represents the number of intersections found.

Now we need to find the corresponding salaries for the names in `setPrjAdj`. Here we need to consider the scenario where no intersection was found, i.e. for a given month, there are no projects with resources associated. The condition for calculating `intersecRoster` prevents that:

```
IF(ISNA(ROWS(setRosterAdj)), 0,…)
```

We can check against `NA()` because our `SPLIT` function returns this value in case of no intersections, so if the condition is `TRUE` we return `NA()`. If the input of `ISNA` is an array it returns an array, so we use `ROWS` to reduce the test to a single cell. If any element of the array has a `#N/A` value the `ROWS` output will be `#N/A`.

In case project intersections are found we need to find the salary and the corresponding new intersections between the date information in `setPrjAdj` and the dates in the roster dataset.

This is done via the following `MAP` call and name the result as `intersecRoster`

```
MAP(INDEX(setPrjAdj,,1), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,2), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,3),
 LAMBDA(name, start, end,
  LET(found, FILTER(HSTACK(starts, endsAdj, salaries), (names=name) * (starts <= end)
        * (endsAdj >= start), NA()), IF(AND(ROWS(found)=1, NOT(ISNA(found))),
        TEXTJOIN(",",, MAX(INDEX(found,,1), start),
        MIN(INDEX(found,,2), end), INDEX(found,,3)), empty)
    )))
```

For each `name`, `start`, and `end` (from `setPrjAdj`),  `HSTACK(starts, endsAdj, salaries)` is filtered by `name` and look for overlaps.

It is used `endsAdj`, instead of `ends` original input data because we need to treat the blank end dates. The result is saved in the `found` name. Now we need to check for an empty set of the `FILTER`. The not found condition of the filter (empty set) is represented by the following output `NA()`. It could happen that the name was not found (some bad spelling or the name is missing).

In case it returns more than one row (it should not happen because the **interval for the roster set should not overlap**, i.e. an employee cannot have two salaries at the same time). We assign an `empty` row. There is no way to determine the salary, so this resource will not contribute to the Salary Monthly Cost. Otherwise, we build the string via `TEXTJOIN` with the corresponding information:  start date, end dates, and the corresponding salary. Where the start and end dates represent the intersection between `start` and `end` dates (from `setPrjAdj`) and the start and end dates from the roster dataset (coming from the `FILTER` output).

Now `intersecRoster` has the following information in CSV format: `start, end, salary`. We do the same operation now to convert the string information into 2D-array, via `SPLIT` and name the result `setRosterAdj`. We use the `case=2`, because all the information is numbers.

```
SPLIT(intersecRoster,2)
```

Here we need to prevent the name was not found in the roster table, to avoid any unexpected result. In case no resource was found, then we return `0` via the following condition:

```
IF(ISNA(ROWS(setRosterAdj)), 0,…)
```

Now we have all the information we are looking for. For calculating the working dates we use `NETWORKDAYS(startEffDates, endEffDates)` where the dates are the corresponding columns from `setRosterAdj` and it is named as `days`.

Finally:

```
SUMPRODUCT(days, effSalaries)
```

Provides the result we are looking for. We named all the columns from `setRosterAdj` using `Eff` (effective) in the name of the corresponding column.

#### Monthly Salary for non-partial allocation

The previous approach calculates the cost based on working days and the daily salary. In case you will like to consider monthly cost instead for months when the resource was allocated the entire month and daily salary for partially allocated months, here is the adjusted formula:

```
=LET(setPrj, A2:E12, setRoster, A15:F33, SOMs, I1:T1, namesPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,1),
 startsPrj, INDEX(setPrj,,4), endsPrj,INDEX(setPrj,,5),names, INDEX(setRoster,,1),
 starts, INDEX(setRoster,,2), ends, INDEX(setRoster,,3),
 monthlySalaries,INDEX(setRoster,,5), dalySalaries,INDEX(setRoster,,6), empty, ",,",
 SPLIT, LAMBDA(x,case, LET(y, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,x),",",";"),
  z, FILTER(y, INDEX(y,,1)<>"", NA()),IFS(case=0, z,case=1, HSTACK(INDEX(z,,1),
  1*CHOOSECOLS(z,2,3)), case=2, 1*z))),
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),endsAdj, IF(ends > 0, ends, EOM),
  overlapsPrj, MAP(namesPrj, startsPrj, endsPrj, LAMBDA(namePrj,startPrj,endPrj,
   IF(AND(startPrj <= EOM, endPrj >= SOM), TEXTJOIN(",",,namePrj, MAX(startPrj, SOM),
    MIN(endPrj, EOM)), empty))),
   setPrjAdj, SPLIT(overlapsPrj,1),
   overlapsRoster, IF(ISNA(ROWS(setPrjAdj)), NA(),
    MAP(INDEX(setPrjAdj,,1), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,2), INDEX(setPrjAdj,,3),
      LAMBDA(name,start,end,
      LET(found, FILTER(HSTACK(starts, endsAdj, dalySalaries, monthlySalaries),
       (names=name) * (starts <= end)  * (endsAdj >= start), NA()),
       IF(AND(ROWS(found)=1, NOT(ISNA(found))),
        TEXTJOIN(",",, MAX(INDEX(found,,1), start), MIN(INDEX(found,,2), end),
          CHOOSECOLS(found,3,4)), empty)
    )))
  ),setRosterAdj, SPLIT(overlapsRoster,2),
  IF(ISNA(ROWS(setRosterAdj)), 0,
    LET(startEffDates, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,1), endEffDates, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,2),
      effDailySalaries, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,3), effMonthlySalaries, INDEX(setRosterAdj,,4),
      days, NETWORKDAYS(startEffDates, endEffDates), monthWorkDays, NETWORKDAYS(SOM, EOM),
      actualSalaries, IF(days = monthWorkDays, effMonthlySalaries, effDailySalaries),
      actualDays, IF(days = monthWorkDays, 1, days),
      SUMPRODUCT(actualDays, actualSalaries)
    ))
  )))
)
```

#### Tip

Since it is a large formula, and Excel doesn't provide a way to debug properly some array functions, it is helpful to have a way to debug some of the partial results. Because `BYCOL` returns a cell per column, it is convenient to define another user's `LAMBDA` function for this purpose inside of the `LET`. For example the following one and name it `DEBUG`.

```
LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(" & ",,x)),
```

then it can be used to return the output of `DEBUG` instead of the final result for testing purposes.